# How can I limit number of applications per student to 3?

Tags: postgresql

I have one table 'Students' and one table 'Applications'.
Each student can apply for max 3 courses. How can I ensure that in database? Trigger? Constraint?

Can you show me how to write it? I'm new to SQL

Comment: please, one question per question

Comment: ok, edited question to leave first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to put a counter on students.  When a row is inserted to Applications increment it, when a row is deleted, decrement it.  Doing this with triggers is very simple.

Then put a constraint on Students so the counter must be <= 3.

Comment: Will ot prevent from adding 4th appliation? Or it just prevent counter from increasing and add Application anyway?

Comment: Assume a trigger on Applications.  You insert the fourth row for a student, and it fires an update of Students to increment the counter to 4.  The constraint on Students fires and rejects it.  This rolls back the entire transaction and the insert fails.  This is where triggers really shine.

Comment: updating the students row acts as a synchronization to protect against  concurrent insertions being allowed when they shouldn't, too.

Comment: @ichibann what I should have said in my original comment was "yes, that prevents the insert"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Applications GROUP BY Student_ID
```

Comment: Assuming those are the attributes used in your tables.